# File system restrictions

Tags: filesystems

OS/File system usually stores metadata along with the files that are being created or stored in file systems.

From a privacy point of view, I see this as the information which is helpful in forensics. So I was wondering if there was any OS/file system which does not store metadata of a file, like the creation date, modification date, user id used during creation (name field of a file in metadata should be stored though obviously).

Also if there doesn't exist any such OS/file system, **can we put restrictions on file systems to not store specific metadata about files?**

Please provide a helpful reference if the answer is yes.

I am using Kali-Rolling (which is based on Debian-Rolling)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be less of a question about the OS itself and more of a question about the file system. For example, NTFS supports users and permissions while FAT32 doesn't (which is why your files are never really secure on a stock flash drive).

Even discussing file systems, this is a very peculiar request as most systems would normally strive to provide as much functionality as possible rather than strip it away.

Although I did not find a system with no metadata, you may be able to use [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata) to chose a file system that supports a minimal amount of metadata.